# How do I return a response to an AngularJS post?

Tags: ruby, angularjs, post

I am posting to a worker that runs my ruby code using AngularJS.

```
$http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://my-url-for-worker-on-iron.io-goes-here",
      data: {input: $scope.newChat}
  })
    .success(function (data)
    {
     // $scope.chats.push(data);
      $scope.chats.push($scope.newChat)

    })
    .error(function (data)
    {
      $scope.errors.push(data);
    });
```

My ruby code takes the payload from the post to the URL, does some stuff, and then have a response in the form of a text string.  But I don't know how to retrieve that response in Angular so it can display on the web-client.

It is posting to a worker on iron.io which just has a few lines of code that has a few file dependencies, no framework is involved.